# Virtual output on an iGPU-only Xorg (Optimus laptop)?

Tags: x11, xorg, multi-monitor, pci-passthrough, gpu-passthrough

On an optimus laptop I've passed a dGPU (Nvidia) through to a virtual machine and all physical display outputs (Display Port alternate modes of USB-C ports and an HDMI port) are only available to the virtual machine now and not to the host. Working without an external monitor on the host becomes difficult and requires rebooting and assigning that dGPU back to host Xorg.

I'm wondering if it's possible instead to create a "VIRTUAL" output on Xorg (using only iGPU) and "tunnel" it somehow in software out through the USB-C ports so that an external monitor can see it as a second Xorg screen?

A suboptimal solution would be sending this virtual monitor output over ethernet to something like a Raspberry Pi, which would then display it on an external monitor, but perhaps there is some way to set it up directly on the laptop?